# Script to calculate total running hours of my EC2 instance?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I'm running AWS Windows based EC2 instance. But its automatically start and stop based client time zone using lambda function. Now i would like to calculate about exactly how many hours running after creation of EC2 instance. Is there any script to calculate total runnung hours?

Comment: Are you asking how many hours it has been running since it was last started, or the total number of hours it has _ever_ been running?

Comment: Yes, i asked for total number of hours running from instance creation time.

Comment: The historical running hours of an instance is not available, but I think you could use a [Cost and Usage Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/what-is-cur.html), which can go down to the individual resource. It will show the hours and the cost for the instance. You _might_ need to activate detailed billing beforehand so it might only give hours and cost _since_ the detailed billing was activated.

Comment: Ok sure. I will check there. Many thanks